# Return index of last occurrence in array

Tags: javascript

I have been working on this for a while now and I have no idea why this isn't working. I've read over it a few times and I can't seem to find the problem in my code.

I thought `if(arr[i] === item)` would check if the current element is equal to the item parameter and if true, return the index.

```
const lastIndexOf = (arr, item) => {
  if(arr.includes(item)){
    for(let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
      if(arr[i] === item){
        return i;
      } else if (arr.includes(i) === false){
        return Number('-1');
      }
    }
  } else if (!arr.length){
    return Number('-1');
  } else {
    return Number('-1');
  }
}

console.log(lastIndexOf([5,5,5,5,0],5));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the else if branch, as it is checking if the array contains the current index, which is nonsensical. Also, just use `-1` instead of `Number('-1')`.

```js
const lastIndexOf = (arr, item) => {
  if(arr.includes(item)){
    for(let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
      if(arr[i] === item){
        return i;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
}

console.log(lastIndexOf([5,5,5,5,0],5));
```

You are currently passing through the array twice, once using `Array#includes` and once with your `for` loop, which is suboptimal. You can simply loop over the array backwards once, like you are currently doing, and return `-1` at the end of the function, since it will only reach there if the item has not been found.

```js
const lastIndexOf = (arr, item) => {
  for(let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    if(arr[i] === item){
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
console.log(lastIndexOf([5,5,5,5,0],5));
```

The [`Array#lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf) method already exists, so there is no need to reinvent the wheel, unless you are trying to make a polyfill.

```js
console.log([5,5,5,5,0].lastIndexOf(5));
```

Comment: Ah perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: @GTA.sprx No problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
} else if (arr.includes(i) === false){
```

You're asking if any of the array members equals the current index. Because `4` (your first checked index) is not accounted for in that array, it returns.

Seems like you don't need that `else if` at all.

```js
const lastIndexOf = (arr, item) => {
  if(arr.includes(item)){
    for(let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
      if(arr[i] === item){
        return i;
      }
    }
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
}

console.log(lastIndexOf([5,5,5,5,0],5));
```

Also, the last, outer `else if` and `else` branches yield the same result, so the `else if` is extraneous, so I removed it.

And `Number('-1')` is an unnecessarily roundabout way of returning `-1`.

---

And actually, your `.includes()` check seems redundant. It's going to have to iterate before you iterate. Might as well just do it once.

```js
const lastIndexOf = (arr, item) => {
  for(let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    if(arr[i] === item){
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

console.log(lastIndexOf([5,5,5,5,0],5));
```